# Passing an iterator to a parent class init in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

What I want to do is to wrap around the `Doc2Vec` class in `gensim` and give it a training method. Normally if I wanted to train a new model I would do the following:

```
import glob
from gensim.models import doc2vec, Doc2Vec


class tagged_documents(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.file_l = [name for name in glob.iglob(path, recursive=True)]
    
    def __iter__(self):
        for f_id, f_path in enumerate(self.file_l):
            with open(f_path, 'r') as f:
                docu = f.read()
                yield doc2vec.TaggedDocument(words=docu, tags=(f'DOC_{f_id}',))



Docs = tagged_documents('/path/to/docs/*')
    
Doc2Vec(Docs, min_count = 100, 
                 vector_size=300, 
                 epochs = 20, 
                 negative = 5, 
                 workers=20, 
                 sample = 1e-5,
                 alpha=0.01,
                 min_alpha=0.0001)
```

and this works fine

now what I want to do is this wrapper

```
class doc2vec_model(Doc2Vec):

    def train(self,docs):
        super(Doc2Vec, self).__init__(docs, min_count = 100, 
                                     vector_size=300, 
                                     epochs = 20, 
                                     negative = 5, 
                                     workers=20, 
                                     sample = 1e-5,
                                     alpha=0.01,
                                     min_alpha=0.0001)

        
Docs = tagged_documents('/path/to/docs/*')
model = doc2vec_model()
model.train(Docs)
```

where I get the exception that `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` when i try to call the `model.train()` function

Comment: What is the point of that wrapper? Using `super` to call your parent's `__init__` method from a *different* method is an an odd choice, at best.

Comment: `Doc2Vec.__init__` has *already* been called as well; since you didn't define `doc2vec_model.__init__`, the inherited method is called when you define `model`.